# agSelectCellEditor is returning object on editing the cell

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I am using agGrid in Angular8. I have one column which when I want to edit should give me exact mapped value in dropdown. I am using agSelectCellEditor for this. 
Here is the code:-

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="categoryGridOptions"
            [rowData]="categoryRowData" [columnDefs]="categoryColDef"  
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS File**

```
export class CategoryComponent{
  categoryRowData: any[]; 
  objCategoryMappings = [{
        0: "No",
        1: "Yes",        
      }];

  categoryColDef = [
       {
            headerName: 'Category Name', field: 'CategoryName',                        
            cellEditor: 'agLargeTextCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                maxLength: '50',
                cols: '20',
                rows: '1'
            }
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Is Subcategory', field: 'IsSubcategory',              
            cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: this.extractValues(this.objCategoryMappings),                                
            },                                          
            cellRenderer: (params) => {               
                return this.mapCategory(params);
            }, 
            refData: this.objCategoryMappings,            
        }];

    extractValues(mappings) {
        return Object.keys(mappings);
    }

    mapCategory(objRowData : any) : string
    {
        if (objRowData.data.IsSubcategory == 1)
            return "Yes";
        else if (objRowData.data.IsSubcategory == 0)
            return "No";        
    }
}
```

When I am clicking on cell then I am getting dropdown as shown in below snapshot:-
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your objCategoryMappings should be

```
objCategoryMappings = {
   0: "No",
   1: "Yes",        
};
```

i.e. remove the square braces - that makes it an array.

Also, by using `Object.keys(objCategoryMappings)` for the values, you are going to have 0 and 1 in your select. If you want 'No' and 'Yes' instead, use `Object.keys(mappings).map((key) => mappings[key]);`

Comment: Removing square braces started showing "No" and  "Yes" in dropdown. Thanks for this. Object.keys(objCategoryMappings) is showing "No", "Yes" but Object.keys(mappings).map((key) => mappings[key]) is showing blank value. So I kept my original code. I need help that when I edit cell then default selection set to "No" always. I want to set dropdown selection mapped to value in cell. If value in cell is Yes then dropdown should show defau;t selection as "Yes". I made it work in UI- Grid but dont know how to set in agGrid.How to make it possible?